# Know the precision of Core Location for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, location, precision

Is there any way to know approximately the precision given by Core Location?
Or to determine whether that location comes from using cellular data / wifi / GPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience of writing a GPS-based speedometer app, the reported GPS accuracy of the iPhone can be fairly far off, based on many dynamic factors: weather, tall buildings, being inside a building (even near a window) or in a vehicle, etc.   The device will report its best guess at accuracy but it's just that, an approximation.   It can claim down to about 16 meters resolution at best, and if you're out entirely in the open on the prairie in sunshine and blue skies with direct lines to the GPS satellites, you might get that.

The CLLocation class offers properties of altitude, position, course, horizontal and vertical accuracy, speed, and time -- but not source of the CLLocation (wifi, gps, etc.)

Comment: Actually, if you're out on a prairie you won't get anything close to accurate GPS data. The GPS on [iPhone/iPad is AGPS](http://gizmodo.com/5015930/giz-explains-what-you-didnt-know-about-the-iphone-3gs-gps), it needs cell towers to get accurate location info.

Comment: Some pretty bad information here. With good line of sight to the sky, an iPhone's GPS is accurate to about 5 meters. Future versions of the hardware and/or software will probably improve on this. And being outside cell tower range will make the GPS take several seconds (or maybe minutes) to find your position from a "cold" start, but once it has that it will be just as accurate and also perfectly fast (split second) to pick up movements.

Comment: My answer is written with direct experience of writing a speedometer app and testing it on a 3GS within real city scenarios, including buildings, cloudy weather, being in a vehicle, etc.    Your "good line of sight to the sky" is a huge major assumption which I account for in my "many dynamic factors" comment.   And waiting "several minutes" for a first read in a speedometer app is a terrible user experience.   I still frequently experience multi-second (not "split second") periods between updates.   All of which adds up to the iphone not being a great speedometer platform, as I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are two properties on `CLLocation`

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationAccuracy verticalAccuracy;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationAccuracy horizontalAccuracy;
```

Looking in the header files and the docs often pays of.